# Бывать/побывать?

Tags: грамматика

This is fairly simple question, I know....but what exactly does бывать mean? Some say it means "to be at", some say it means " to happen"???

Answer (score 4):

«*Бывать*»  usually means *"to happen"*, *"to occur*" or *"to be (occasionally)"*. However, it can be used with modifiers of place, so that the resulting phrase is translated as *"to be at somewhere"*

- *«он бывает просто невыносим»*  - *"sometimes he is just impossible"*
- *«этот праздник бывает нечасто»* - *"this holiday does not occur often"*
- *«он бывает дома только ночью»* - *"he is at home only by night"*

Comment: It's worth adding here that some people can say "бывай", which would mean "bye / see you"

Answer (score 0):

I'd say `бывать` means `to happen` or `to happen to be at`:

> Летом здесь часто **бывают** дожди. - It rains often here in summer.
>
> Я никогда раньше **не бывал** в Москве. - I have never been to Moscow before.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can say "Бывает" by one word, what means "It can happen"